# Problemas com <p:poll> que não encontra Id

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Gente, tô com uma div que precisa ser atualizada em períodos de 5s, porém está dando erro dizendo que a ID não é encontrada.

```
<h:form id="form">      
   <br />
   <center><h:outputLabel value="Visão Geral" class="titlePrincipal" /></center>

   <p:poll interval="#{controleBean.ciclo}" update="refreshArea" />
   <div id="refreshArea">
        <ui:repeat var="abr" value="#{controleBean.auxiliarbr}" varStatus="status">
            <div class="containerBomba" title="Descrição">
                <div class="reservatorio reservatorio#{controleBean.verificarNivelReservatorio()}" title="Reservatório">
                    <h:outputText value="#{abr.reservatorio.nomeReservatorio} (#{controleBean.verificarNivelReservatorio()}%)" />
                </div>

                <ui:repeat var="b" value="#{abr.bombas}" varStatus="status2">
                    <div class="bomba bomba#{controleBean.verificarEstadoBomba(b)}" title="Bomba">
                        <h:outputText value="#{controleBean.verificarNomeBomba(abr, b)}" />
                    </div> 
                </ui:repeat>
            </div>  
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Exception

```
Out 27, 2015 12:04:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/Hidros] threw exception [Cannot find component with expression "refreshArea" referenced from "form:j_idt56".] with root cause
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression "refreshArea" referenced from "form:j_idt56".
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentInternal(SearchExpressionFacade.java:422)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:200)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentsForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:147)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addExpressions(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.component.poll.PollRenderer.encodeEnd(PollRenderer.java:61)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tentei por :form:refreshArea, mas não deu certo também.

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Tenta colocar dentro de um `p:panel` ou de um `h:panelGroup` e tenta atualizar passando `'id do form':'id do container'`, onde 'container' vai ser o `p:panel` ou o `h:panelGroup`.

Comment: você não vai conseguir da update em componentes que não são do JSF. Substitua sua div por um componente do jsf. Complemento: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13011934/5165064

Answer (score 1):

A solução foi só trocar a `div` por `p:panel`.